# ¿Cómo hago que el usuario ingrese un listado hasta donde desee y después mostrar ese listado y el número de palabras que ingresó?

Tags: java

El algoritmo es un menú de opciones sobre el reino animal, el problema lo tengo en el caso 1 y 3, creo que es algo muy básico pero, necesito ayuda.

algoritmo:
Realizar un programa en JAVA que permita clasificar los animales del reino animal, este sistema debe mostrar el siguiente menú de opciones:
animales mamíferos - carnívoros
animales mamíferos - herbívoros
animales mamíferos - carroñeros

caso 1, se debe ingresar por teclado los animales que solo coman carne,, debe preguntar si come carne o no, mostrar un mensaje "no es carnívoro, vuelva a ingresar otro", además mostrarlos por consola, debe salir del programa cuando se digite 0.

caso 2, debe mostrar por pantalla los animales que consumen hierba, este programa debe mostrar hasta 5 de esta especie y finalizar el programa.

caso 3, se debe ingresar por teclado solo animales carroñeros, debe preguntar si come carne fresca o descompuesta, mostrar un mensaje "no es carroñero, debe mostrar la lista y el total de animales ingresados, salir del programa cuando digite 0.

package recuperacion_reinoanimal;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recuperacion_reinoanimal {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    int opcions;
    String animal;
    boolean salir = false;
    
    System.out.println("***********************************************");
    System.out.print("Clasificación de los animales del reino animal");
    System.out.println("\n***********************************************");

    
    
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\n*Menú de opciones*");
        System.out.println("\n1. Animales vertebrados acuáticos - carnívoros");   
        System.out.println("2. Animales vertebrados acuáticos - herbívoros"); 
        System.out.println("3. Animales vertebrados acuáticos - carroñeros"); 
        System.out.println("4. Datos del autor del sistema");
        System.out.println("5. Salir");

            System.out.print("\nSeleccione una opción: "); 
            opcions = reader.nextInt();

        while (!salir){
                switch (opcions){
                                case 1:  

                                System.out.print("\nPor favor ingrese el nombre de pez que coma carne: ");
                                animal = entrada.nextLine();
                    
                                int carne = 0;
                                
                                System.out.print("\n¿Come carne?");
                                System.out.println("\n1.Si \n2.No");

                                System.out.print("\nElije 1 o 2: ");
                                carne = reader.nextInt();

                                if (carne == 1){
                                System.out.println ("Es carnívoro");
                                salir = true;      
                                }if (carne == 2){ 
                                System.out.println ("No es carnívoro, ingrese otro");
                                salir = false;
                                } else {
                                if (carne == 0) {
                                salir = true;}
                                }
                                System.out.println("Los animales ingresados fueron: "+animal);
                                break;


                                case 2:
                                System.out.print("\nEstos son algunos ejemplos de peces herbívoros:");
                                System.out.println("\na. Pez loro azul");
                                System.out.println("b. Pez cirujano");
                                System.out.println("c. Chopa blanca");
                                System.out.println("d. Salpa");
                                System.out.println("e. Loro manchado");
                                salir = true;
                                break;


                                case 3:
                                System.out.print("\nPor favor ingrese peces carroñeros: ");
                                animal = entrada.nextLine();
                                int carroña;
                                System.out.print("\n¿Su animal consume carne fresca o descompuesta?");
                                System.out.println("\n1.Fresca \n2.Descompuesta");
                                System.out.print("\nElije 1 o 2: ");
                                carroña = reader.nextInt();
                                if (carroña == 1){System.out.println ("Efectivamente es carroñero");
                                salir = true;      
                                }else{ System.out.println ("No es carroñero, vuelva a ingresar otro");
                                salir = false;
                                }
                                break;


                                case 4:
                                System.out.println("\nDatos del autor del sistema:");
                                System.out.println("Nombres completos: Alberto Gregory Parrales lino");
                                System.out.println("Curso: Primero");
                                System.out.println("Paralelo: C");
                                System.out.println("Sexo: Masculino");
                                System.out.println("Edad: 19");
                                salir = true;
                                break;


                                case 5:  
                                salir = true; 
                                break;


                                default: 
                                System.out.println("\nERROR NO EXISTE ESTA OPCION\n"); 
                                salir = true;
                                break; 
                }
}
}
```

}

Comment: [¡Aquí no hacemos tareas!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320) Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Debes primero que nada tener un codigo en donde hayas intentado algo no ? por favor agregalo acá asi poder corregirlo.

Comment: Disculpa @Excorpion ya lo edité

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español; No encuentro mucho sentido al planteamiento de la pregunta, cuando dice ingrese por teclado los animales que solo comen carne y además mostrarlo por consola; Aquí se me ocurren 2 casos: 1) Que muestre el mismo nombre del animal que se ha ingresado por teclado. 2)Que se almacene en un arreglo los animales que cumplan con la condición y mostrarlos al presionar la tecla 0 o mejor que tuviese un sub menu que diga mostrar los animales ingresados.

Comment: Hola @Joshin es que mi docente no se da a entender, pero solo quiero ayuda en el caso 3, primero como muestro la lista y total de animales ingresados.

Comment: @ABELCASTILLO al decir lista se refiere a  que uses un Arraylist el cual es una clase que te permite almacenar datos temporalmente,similar a un array , para las condicionales no necesariamente,debes hacer usos de números puedes usar next o nextline para poder ingresar si/no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que hacer uso de una [lista](https://blog.codmind.com/listas-en-java/) para almacenar los nombres de los peces que vayas ingresando, el caso 3 de tu problema quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
List<String>carroñeros =new ArrayList<>();

while (!salir){
            switch (opcions){
                case 1:  
                //código                

                case 2:
                //código

                case 3:                    
                    String continuar;
                    int carroña;
                    do{
                        System.out.print("\nPor favor ingrese peces carroñeros: ");
                        animal = entrada.nextLine();
                        
                        System.out.println("\n¿Su animal consume carne fresca o descompuesta?");
                        System.out.println("1.Fresca \n2.Descompuesta");
                        System.out.print("\nElije 1 o 2: ");
                        carroña = entrada.nextInt();
                        entrada.nextLine();//limpieza al buffer
                        if (carroña == 1){System.out.println ("Efectivamente es carroñero");
                            carroñeros.add(animal);                            
                        }else{ 
                            System.out.println ("No es carroñero, vuelva a ingresar otro");                            
                        }
                        System.out.println("Desea ingresa otro pez? [Si - No]");
                        continuar=entrada.nextLine();                        
                    }while(continuar.equals("si"));
 
                    //mostramos la cantidad de peces carroñeros haciendo uso del método size().
                    System.out.println("Cantidad de peces carroñeros: "+carroñeros.size());

                    /*mostrando el listado de peces que se guardaron en la lista
                      para ello hacemos uso de un foreach
                    */
                    for (String pez : carroñeros) {
                        System.out.println(pez);
                    }
                    salir=true;
                    break;

                case 4:
                //código


                case 5:  
                salir = true; 
                break;


                default: 
                System.out.println("\nERROR NO EXISTE ESTA OPCION\n"); 
                salir = true;
                break; 
            }
        }
```

**Observaciones**

1. Cuando realizas una lectura por teclado de tipo numérico tienes que realizar [una limpieza del buffer](https://www.clasesdeinformaticaweb.com/java-desde-cero/el-buffer-de-la-clase-scanner/)
2. Sólo es necesario crear 1 variable para leer los datos por teclado, en tu caso haces  Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
3. Trata de no crear variables que contengan la letra **ñ**